# Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 fails (stopped at the command screen root)

Tags: system-installation

I am using Ubuntu 12:04 , I try to upgrade to 14:04 . Just because the process is very long and less my temper so that the upgrade has not been finished , my laptop shutdown (assuming it could be continued tomorrow ) . But after I tried to continue on the next day turns Ubuntu - only entry in the display command can not get to the desktop Ubuntu .

In the command screen , enter the root prompt

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command,

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy ... It's that I have done :
I have to download the application ubuntu 14:04 . I give the command lsb_release , note that ubuntu has version 14:04 . Then I gave the command : sudo do-release - upgrade -d .
On the screen shown : Checking new ....
The process is a long time . Is this normal ?